# ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME on table failed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, temporal-tables

I have:

- table with existing data
- SQL Server 2016 SP1
- SQL Server Management Studio 17.5

I am using the following statement to make a make my table a temporal one:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroups]
ADD [SysStartTime] DATETIME2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN CONSTRAINT DF_AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroups_SysStart DEFAULT GETUTCDATE()  
   ,[SysEndTime] DATETIME2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN CONSTRAINT DF_AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroups_SysEnd DEFAULT CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), '9999-12-31 23:59:59'),   
PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([SysStartTime], [SysEndTime]); 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroups]   
SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroupsChanges));
```

The issue:

On my local SQL instance I have many databases; it's very strange that the query runs successfully on some of them, and on some of them it gives me the following error:

> Msg 13542, Level 16, State 0, Line 51 ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME on
>   table 'dbo.AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroups’ failed because there are
>   open records with start of period set to a value in the future.

Sometimes, when I am debugging/executing the query, the initial query runs successfully.

I read, that this could be because I have existing data in the table. So, I have change the logic like this:

- create buffer table and populated it with all records
- delete the records from the original table
- create the temporal table
- move the records back and drop the buffer table

and again, on some databases it is OK, and on other is not. Trying to resolve the issue I have [found](https://matthewmcgiffen.com/2017/10/24/implementing-temporal-tables-where-you-have-existing-data/) the following:

> For the StartDate I’ve specified the current UTC date – this could be
>   any date and time that’s not in the future, though note it should be a
>   UTC one. If I’d tried to use GETDATE, as I’m currently on British
>   Summer Time, I would get the following error: Msg 13542, Level 16,
>   State 0, Line 51 ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME on table
>   ‘TestAudit.dbo.SomeData’ failed because there are open records with
>   start of period set to a value in the future.

What does the above means? I need to change the machine time? Or because my local machine is not on UTC time I am getting this error sometimes?

Comment: Did you see this post? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vikas_rana/2016/11/29/msg-13575-or-msg-13597-error-message-while-adding-period-columns/

Comment: Yes, check the comments, also. I have find such workaround in this forum, too, but it changed nothing. I need to understand how to change the time settings in order to get this work. Also, I am having the issue even if the table is empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I have found how to fix my issue, but I am not going to accept this as answer as I am not able to explain what is causing the problem and guarantee this will work anytime. It's fix found after a lot of testing and I will be glad if someone can bring more light here.

---

I have never used `datetime2` with precision. So, I went back to the source of this format `datetime2(0)` - [Alter Non-Temporal Table to be System-Versioned Temporal Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table#alter-non-temporal-table-to-be-system-versioned-temporal-table). The only difference with the script I have been using was the date time function. I used `GETUTCDATE()` as I do not need to be so precised with `datetime(0)`(`2018-03-15 07:21:02` for example) and in the example it is  `SYSUTCDATETIME()`. So, I have changed it.

I have create a script which is dropping a database if exists, restoring a database from backup and then executing my code in a loop (as I said I get the error sometimes and it was very hard to reproduce it).

I have run a the script a lot of times and I was getting different number of fails (sometimes 70%, sometimes 50%, sometimes below):

[image]

I have found this [Why is GETUTCDATE earlier than SYSDATETIMEOFFSET?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175695/why-is-getutcdate-earlier-than-sysdatetimeoffset) discussion about differences between old and new date time functions. Then build the following query:

```
DECLARE @UTC DATETIME2(0) = GETUTCDATE();
DECLARE @SYSUTC DATETIME2(0) = SYSUTCDATETIME();

WHILE DATEPART(SECOND, @UTC) = DATEPART(SECOND, @SYSUTC)
BEGIN;
    SET @UTC  = GETUTCDATE();
    SET @SYSUTC  = SYSUTCDATETIME();
END;

SELECT @UTC AS [UTC]
      ,@SYSUTC AS [SYS UTC]
      ,DATEPART(SECOND, @UTC) AS [UTC sec]
      ,DATEPART(SECOND, @SYSUTC) AS [SYS UTC sec]
      ,CASE WHEN @UTC < @SYSUTC THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [TimeTravelPossible]
      ,CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), @UTC) AS [UTC date]
      ,CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), @SYSUTC) AS [SYS UTC date]
      ,IIF(CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), @UTC) = CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), @SYSUTC), 1, 0) AS [Are The Same];
```

I just wanted to check if I can get different `datetime2(0)` dates using sys and not sys date time function. And of course it is possible.

[image]

Maybe, the checks that the engine is making is doing something like this, comparing its current date with my newer date and this is causing the error - `open records with start of period set to a value in the future.`

I have change the script like this and executed 1 000 times last night - no errors were generated. So, I believe I have fixed this particular issue, but I can't be sure.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroups]
ADD [SysStartTime] DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN CONSTRAINT DF_AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroups_SysStart DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME()  
   ,[SysEndTime] DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN CONSTRAINT DF_AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroups_SysEnd DEFAULT CONVERT(DATETIME2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'),   
PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([SysStartTime], [SysEndTime]); 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroups]   
SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroupsChanges));
```

Comment: I had a strange encounter with this also getting the same error as you. I tried hacking around the issue by doing each component of the alter one piece at a time, but the "PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME" thing is very particular. I somehow got it to work after adding my start/end columns, then dropping them, then on a last ditch effort running the whole statement again - this worked. Just be aware that this is a known [MS bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4013112/fix-add-period-for-system-time-failed-error-when-you-add-period-column)

Comment: @gotqn Thanks for solution

Comment: @dyslexicanaboko Thanks for that bug link. However, it's only for memory-optimised tables. Do you know if there's a recognized MS bug for non-memory-optimised tables?

Comment: @ReversedEngineer no sir I don't know. However if you can, try to use the latest version of SQL Server if you can, there is a good chance whatever the problem is has been fixed already in the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

The real reason behind this issue is because SQL Server doesn't truncate the unwanted precision from `datetime`/`datetime2`, it **rounds** it!

To show this simply, I cast a time value with milliseconds equal or greater than 500

```
SELECT CAST('10:10:59.563' AS TIME(0))
```

Result is: 10:11:00, which is obviously greater than 10:10:59.563

The same applies to `DATETIME(n)`.

In your original example, you're taking `GETUTCDATE()`, which returns a `DATETIME`, which has a precision of 3(ish).
Right off the bat, you're getting a rounded datetime which will sometimes be rounded up into the future.
You will experience the same issue casting to a lesser precision from `SYSUTCDATETIME`,
e.g. `CAST(SYSUTCDATETIME() AS DATETIME2(3))` - where the 4th fractional digit is '5' or above, the date is rounded up into the future.

To mitigate this, you can offset the rounding with `DATEADD` to effectively truncate the unwanted precision,
e.g.

```
CAST(DATEADD(MILLISECONDS, -500, SYSUTCDATETIME()) AS DATETIME(0))
CAST(DATEADD(MILLISECONDS, -50, SYSUTCDATETIME()) AS DATETIME(1))
CAST(DATEADD(MILLISECONDS, -5, SYSUTCDATETIME()) AS DATETIME(2))
CAST(DATEADD(MICROSECONDS, -500, SYSUTCDATETIME()) AS DATETIME(3))
CAST(DATEADD(MICROSECONDS, -50, SYSUTCDATETIME()) AS DATETIME(4))
CAST(DATEADD(MICROSECONDS, -5, SYSUTCDATETIME()) AS DATETIME(5))
```

How this works:

If we want to truncate down to two decimal positions (DP), we need to subtract half of the smallest non-zero amount (e.g. 0.01 / 2 = 0.005) from the value before rounding.

Some examples:

```
7.004999999999 - 0.005 = 6.999999999999 round to two DP = 7.00
7.000999999999 - 0.005 = 6.995999999999 round to two DP = 7.00
7.009999999999 - 0.005 = 7.004999999999 round to two DP = 7.00
```

So to edit your provided code, the proper way to use `DATETIME(0)` in this situation would be:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroups]
  ADD [SysStartTime] DATETIME2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN
          CONSTRAINT DF_AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroups_SysStart 
              DEFAULT CONVERT(DATETIME(0), DATEADD(MILLISECONDS, -500, SYSUTCDATETIME())),
      [SysEndTime] DATETIME2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN
          CONSTRAINT DF_AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroups_SysEnd
              DEFAULT CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), '9999-12-31 23:59:59'),   
      PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([SysStartTime], [SysEndTime]); 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroups]   
SET (
    SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (
        HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroupsChanges
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when updating a lot of tables in one transaction ( via an entity framework migration)
It seemed to turn out that I needed to update the tables in order of referential integrity, doing the child tables first.

I split the process into several migrations.

Answer (score -1):

This worked on SQL Server and Azure SQL (PaaS) environment.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroups]
     ADD SysStartTime datetime2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN 
         CONSTRAINT DF_SysStart DEFAULT DATEADD(second, -1, SYSUTCDATETIME()),
     SysEndTime datetime2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN 
         CONSTRAINT DF_SysEnd DEFAULT CONVERT(datetime2 (0), '9999-12-31 23:59:59'),
     PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime);
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroups]
SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[AnalysisCustomRollupsV2JoinGroups_History]));

GO
```